# SO apparently doesn't know that asterisks are allowed in URLs

Tags: bug, hyperlinks

SO cuts off URLs after an asterisk, which isn't correct. Here is an example URL:

https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes

Please note that `*-attributes` is a valid part of the URL.

Originally, the full URL looks like this:

```
https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes
```

Comment: I'm surprised that nobody suggested the obvious workaround: "*don't use silly URLs*";)

Comment: I read this as "my significant other doesn't know that asterisks are allowed in URLs" and was _very_ confused for a moment.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar I've just learned a new term in English, thanks :)

Comment: On [meta.se]: [Chat / markdown do not parse links or tags with an asterisk in them](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/159551/193139) · [A star in a URL breaks the linkification in posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/20936/193139) · [Asterisks break URLs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/117698/193139)

Comment: It's not just asterisks.  I reported [Markdown parser does not recognise all valid URL paths](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/172173) over three year ago, but nobody gave a ****.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/220324/

Comment: @eggyal Unfortunately, the last word of your comment got cut off.

Comment: @unor  asteriks instead of asterisk :(

Comment: @senshin see this ^

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This looks like an issue with the [markdown parser](https://code.google.com/archive/p/markdownsharp/). I'm not sure SO has any say over that.

However, maybe you can [submit an issue](https://code.google.com/archive/p/markdownsharp/issues). Just make sure to check if it hasn't been submitted before.

Comment: OK, I will. But AFAIK one can "overwrite" some of the markdown functionalities, SO has some SO-related tricks. So if they won't solve this, I think SO still can do this on its own. Will accept as soon as SO will let me do this.

Comment: The correct link to submit issue on markdown: https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/issues/new but I wanted to do this, I clicked "preview" and... on Github it works fine (AFAIK they use markdown too). Right now I am unable to test "pure" markdown, but or Github modified something, or indeed this is a SO specific issue.

Comment: I believe this is "pure" markdown: http://dillinger.io/ - and no, there are no issues there with URLs

Comment: @konrad_firm so if you don't buy the explanation why have you accepted the answer?

Comment: I'm not complaining ;-)

Comment: @MartinSmith Well, first I accepted the answer then I made my investigation. But the primary reason I don't want to undo my acceptance is this: I knew SO uses markdown, yet I did not even think this could be related to markdown :) This was the moment I thought it's time to leave my office and get some sleep. And I'm grateful to Martin for this :)

Comment: @Cerbrus my explanation above ^ :)

Comment: An upstream bug is still a bug in your own product

Answer (score 35):

As a workaround you can use a backslash (\) to escape the asterisk (*) where it might be interpreted as markdown:

```
https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-\*-attributes
```

https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes

Though a better solution would be to use an explicit link with descriptive text:

```
[3.2.5.9 Embedding custom non-visible data with the data-\* attributes][1]
  [1]: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes
```

[3.2.5.9 Embedding custom non-visible data with the data-* attributes](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes)

Comment: I think this is the correct way, not a workaround. `*` has special meaning in markdown, and if you don't want that meaning you should escape it. And no need to repeat the URL, you can use `https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-\*-attributes` directly.

Comment: @Oriol Ah, I didn't think of that. I've updated my answer with your more direct solution.

Comment: @Oriol then why it works fine on http://dillinger.io/ ? I understand this is a "pure" markdown implementation.

Comment: @Oriol if linkifying urls in the text is a markdown feature then the markdown parser should support bare `*` in urls.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian That's if you assume nobody ever wants to apply formatting to a URL.  That is of course a false assumption.  Treating unescaped markdown characters in URLs as markdown is the only way to allow that behavior, while still allowing those characters to be in the URL through the various methods described in this answer.

Comment: @Servy: incorrect. I don't assume that. In a rare case, when you want to format different parts of an url differently, you could use the explicit `[]()` syntax. Parts inside `[]` are not linkified based on their content -- they are as a whole link to whatever is inside `()`.

Answer (score 30):

You can always percent encode troublesome characters. Try it with `%2A` in place of the `*`.

Comment: And asterisk *is* on the list of reserved characters, so that's the preferred way to express the URL anyway.

Comment: I think this is what SE did some time ago, but it was not correct (see [*Percent-encoding of asterisks (\*) in links*](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/q/2254/24166)). A URL with the path `/foo*bar` is *not* equivalent to a URL with the path `/foo%2Abar`, because it’s a reserved character.