# Hyperlink with apostrophe doesn't link correctly

Tags: bug, hyperlinks

Perhaps this isn't a bug but I found an answer that had a link inline (i.e. not inserted with markup) which Stack Overflow linked to the wrong page.  The reason: there is an apostrophe in the middle of the address!  The answer is located here: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7655979/revisions (see revision 3, I've edited the link to go to the correct location).

So is this a Stack Overflow bug that it incorrectly determines the link, or are links with apostrophes in them inherently ambiguous so there's no good solution?  (Also, I guess the answer might be "it is a bug, but a markup one not SOs".

Comment: Apostrophes are not valid URL components. You need to ensure you get the *escaped* URL: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katz%27s_back-off_model

Comment: See this related question: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319585/so-apparently-doesnt-know-that-asterisks-are-allowed-in-urls?rq=1 and one of the answers there suggests the same solution you applied as well as the option Martijn offered. Not sure if it is enough of a match to count as duplicate